# Android Json String not filling list

Tags: android, json, list

hi there I'm not getting any errors but for some reason its not filling my list the json feed has an array of news inside that is a tag called title and i want to display the titles in a list view. but at the moment it just displays a blank screen. heres my code

```
try {

    // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("news");

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        items.add(oneObject.getString("title"));
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item,
            items));
    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) arg1).getText(), 1000).show();
        }

    });

} catch (Exception e) {
    // In your production code handle any errors and catch the
    // individual exceptions
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the JSON you're trying to parse. We're not magicians ;)

Comment: sorry heres the json {"code":200,"error":null,"data":{"news":[{"news_id":"8086","title":"Tickets for Player of the Year award on general sale",

Answer (score 0):

To start debugging something like this, figure out where the data is, and where it isn't. Android has some excellent debugging routines, the `Log.v` statements. Basically, start putting code like this in, and see where your problem lies. If you get it down to a specific thing that isn't working right, then give us the inputs to the block, the outputs your getting, and what it should be.

```
Log.v("JSON",""+items)
```

Comment: I have put that in but not getting anything in LogCat Log cat is only showing stuff from yesterday even though I've tried to use it a few times today and its not logging anything